# Set multiple keys at once with global-set-key?

Tags: key-bindings

Is it somehow possible to set multiple keys with `global-set-key` without having to repeat the statement, like setting multiple variables with `setq`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, no.  `C-h f global-set-key` tells you what the function's signature is:

> `global-set-key` is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `subr.el`.
>
> **`(global-set-key KEY COMMAND)`**
>
> Give `KEY` a global binding as `COMMAND`.
>
> ...

The function accepts only a single key sequence and a single command.

If you really wanted to save multiple occurrences of the text `(global-set-key` and `)` then you could write a function to do that.  E.g.:

```lisp
(defun my-g-s-k (&rest k+c)
  "..."
  (let (key cmd)
    (while k+c
      (global-set-key (car k+c) (cadr k+c))
      (setq k+c  (cddr k+c)))))

(my-g-s-k "\C-o"    'forward-char
          "\M-o"    'backward-char
          "\C-\M-o" 'forward-line)
```